# Is there a word for a person that other people listen to?

Tags: word-request, vocabulary

I need to know if there is a word for someone who people like to listen to his/her speeches, talks, lectures, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of a broad question since people may like to listen to someone speak for different reasons, adjectives used to describe a good orator are

> eloquent
>   articulate
>   knowledgable
>   engaging
>   charismatic
>   well-spoken

Comment: Yes why you "like" a speaker greatly depends on the reason. You might listen to a scientist because he is knowledgeable, to a movie star because she is charismatic, and to a preacher because he is eloquent.

Comment: But the OP asked for a word for the person.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an inspirator, one who inspires or imbues an body of people with a varying array of possible emotions. You will find the usage of this word as vague, and will be hard pressed to find a complete dictionary entry on such.

Comment: Can you provide any evidence that anyone actually uses this word?

Comment: Inspirator, while listed in some dictionaries as someone who inspires, isn’t often used that way. It is more commonly used as “An inspirator is a device, similar to a venturi tube and an orifice plate, which mixes a fuel gas with atmospheric air in a precise ratio to regulate burn characteristics.” (Wikipedia)

Answer (score -1):

Inspirational speaker

Orator

Demagogue

Rabble-rouser

Cunning linguist (careful how you say this!)